# wiringPi installation issue

Tags: installation, raspberry-pi, wiringpi

I am trying to stall wiringpi in the raspberry for using the GPIO in C but the message says that:

"Package wiringpi is not available but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsolited , or is only available from nother source"

Does anyone knows why this is happening? I already check some similiar issues and nothing. The upgrade is already done . Or which apt does substitute wiringpi
(I am using the raspberry pi4)

Thanks a lot and have great day!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I aleady found a solution!! thanks anyway here is the link just in case anyone has te same problem

http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/

$ git clone git://git.drogon.net/wiringPi

$ cd ~/wiringPi

$ git pull origin

$ ./build

Answer (score 0):

I know the question already has an answer, but for me, the solution was slightly different and maybe it could be helpful to somebody...

In my case, the issue was due to a broken Debian installation, running the following command solved it: `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Afterward, WiringPi was installed with the normal procedure.